# Multiple taxonomy term repeating results in views. Remove repetition but keep the term

Tags: mysql, drupal-7, view, drupal-taxonomy

NOTE: I dont want to remove the repeating node, more like merging them.

I have a view that pulls a `seminar` content type along with the taxonomy term attached to the content type. In the content type the term reference field pulling the taxonomy term is a multivalue field. So whenever there is more than one taxonomy term attached to the node the view result is repeated. So using view and its api what I want is

What I have now when view pulls the result is

```
Nid Speaker name | Location | Time 
----------------------------------
12  Sanjok Gurung| London   | 1900
11  John         | London   | 1900
10  Sally        | London   | 1900
10  Molly        | London   | 1900
```

So the above table, Sally and Molly are term reference selected in the same node.

What I want is

```
Nid Speaker name | Location | Time 
----------------------------------
12  Sanjok Gurung| London   | 1900
11  John         | London   | 1900
10  Sally,Molly  | London   | 1900
```

I tried manipulating the results from `views_pre_render` but this method feels like it is so dirty. There should be a better clean solutions

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this contrib module. 
URL: https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator

You can read the documentation from the below url. http://cgit.drupalcode.org/views_aggregator/plain/README.txt?id=refs/heads/7.x-1.x

Answer (score 0):

This is not a view issue actually,

If you open the `Manage Display` of `seminar content type` and try to edit the display settings of `entity reference` **FORMAT** format drop-down select `separator` you can change what kind of separator you may want to choose from settings tab like `(comma or dash)`

**Note:** Make sure to edit the exact `display mode` *(teaser or Full content or Default)* which ever is used in the view.

May be this will resolve the issue.